# Different sbt-web pipeline task settings in development vs production?

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, uglifyjs, sbt-web

I would like an sbt setting to have a different value when running in development (`sbt run`) than production (`sbt dist` / `sbt start`).

Specifically I am using [sbt-uglify](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify). I use it in development to concatenate javascript assets into one file. I have compression and mangling disabled in development because it makes code more difficult to debug.

In production I would like to use compression in order to remove blocks of debug code (`if (DEBUG) { ... }`) which is possible using the dead code removal features of uglifyjs.

I expected this to work:

```
// "in Assets" to use uglify in dev & prod
pipelineStages in Assets := Seq(uglify)

// enable compression and mangling in prod
UglifyKeys.compress := true
UglifyKeys.mangle := true

// disable in development (DOESN'T WORK! Values are always true)
UglifyKeys.compress in Assets := false
UglifyKeys.mangle in Assets := false
```

Comment: The use of `in Assets` and not is probably `pipelineStages` specific. Do you need to run `uglify` in dev?

Comment: It's only used to concatenate all `*.js` into one file. I couldn't use `sbt-concat` for reasons I can't recall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this

```
def optimize = System.getProperty("optimize") != null

UglifyKeys.compress := optimize
UglifyKeys.mangle := optimize
```

Then I can run `sbt dist -J-Doptimize`